# Relation between $r_{outer}$ and $r_{inner}$ of a distribution with two concentric rings

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to solve the following question. If anyone get an idea please give me hint.

Consider a distribution made up two cocentric ring one with $r_{inner}$ radius and the other with $r_{outer}$. If points are drawn equiprobabily from either ring and unifotmly in angle, what is the relation between  $r_{inner}$ and $r_{outer}$ if this distribution is unit-variance?

Comment: Your rings are presumably two dimensional.  What does "unit variance" mean?

Comment: consider $s=re^{j\phi}$ which shows the location of each point on the ring and $\phi$ is uniformely distributed over $ [0, 2\pi)$, it means $E[s^2]=1$